# Find input class in DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

Hi I'm using CEFsharp to automate through a website and fill in fields etc.. As so far I have not been able to get jquery working i'm using javascript and have come across a problem.

When I try to find an input field:

```
<input class="quantity" type="text" value="1" maxlength="2" size="2" name="quantity">
```

I use javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0].value = '3';
```

This works fine the first time and 3 items are added to the basket.
However once items are in the basket a span class is created so the array placement of the class quantity is no longer 0 and so does not find the input class that I am looking for.

```
<strong class="quantity">3</strong>
```

I know in jquery this would be easy but for the time being i have to use javascript so what is the javascript equivalent of doing:

```
jquery $('input.classname')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `document.querySelector("input.quantity");`. [Compatible table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: worked a treati don t know why i couldn t find that thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use querySelector() // cross platform
 and querySelectorAll() // modern browser